# How to return the property of an interface for a specific type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I need to return the properties of an interface only for a specific type. I created this example to explain it better:

```js
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  city: string;
  hasDriverLicense: boolean;
}

let people: IPerson[] = [];

people.push({name: "John", age: 20, city: "Honolulu", hasDriverLicense: false});
people.push({name: "Mary", age: 25, city: "Rio de Janeiro", hasDriverLicense: true});
people.push({name: "Stuart", age: 30, city: "Dubai", hasDriverLicense: true});
```

How do I return, for example, only string-type properties of the variable?

```
// Expected result:
[{
  "name": "John",
  "city": "Honolulu",
}, {
  "name": "Mary",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
}, {
  "name": "Stuart",
  "city": "Dubai",
}]
```

Are there any methods that allow me to specify the type of property I need? Or would it be necessary to go further and create a function with some `if`s?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the _type_ for this (use Pick or Omit from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) or how to write the code to actually do it (which is just a general JS question)?

Comment: I am asking how to write the code to do it.

Comment: So did you research that? It seems like it's just a basic .map call.

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear: I'd just like to know if there are any methods available to return the types of properties I need.

Comment: The type metadata doesn't exist at runtime, because TypeScript erases it in compilation to JavaScript. Hence my question about whether you're trying to write a type (maybe a mapped type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) or the actual implementation (use `typeof`)? Either way it's not clear what research you've done into this.

Comment: Actually I tried to do something like this: `people.filter(person => typeof person == "string")` but it just returns me objects.

Comment: You have an array of _objects_, none of them are strings. You need to iterate over the entries in each object. But it doesn't seem like the typing is the problem, you're stuck on basic JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own method for it.
For example:

```js
function extractDataBasedOnDataType(arr: any[], type: string) {
    let newArr = arr.slice();
    return newArr.map((item: any) => {
        Object.keys(item).forEach((key: string) => {
            if (typeof item[key] !== type) {
                delete item[key];
            }
        });
        return item;
    });
}

console.log(extractDataBasedOnDataType(people, "string"))

/** Result:
[{
  "name": "John",
  "city": "Honolulu"
}, {
  "name": "Mary",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
}, {
  "name": "Stuart",
  "city": "Dubai"
}] 
*/
```

The above code will only work for [basic data types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) because typeof only works for basic types.

Comment: I just accepted you answer and complemented it with the result. Thanks man.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that, although it copies the `arr` via `.map`, that's _shallow_ - you're deleting those entries from the objects in the original array, too. It should probably be more consistent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have used `arr.slice()` which makes deep copy of the array.

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47738344/3001761). You make two shallow copies, the slice is therefore not just not deep but pointless.

Comment: ohh! thanks.
Then you can use spread operator `let newItem = {...item}`, and delete irrelevant key-value pairs from it. I have search about spread operator and it does not deep copy for nested arrays and objects, in that case `let newItem = {...item, key: ...item.nestedObject}`

Answer (score 1):

As [this article says](https://www.piotrl.net/typescript-condition-subset-types/) you could define a type definition that picks only the keys you want for your definition.

Here is the type:

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
const result: SubType<IPerson, string> = {city: "Whatever", name: "Whatever"} // only city and name can be added.
```